# Karnaugh Mapping Assignment

Tags: design, digital-logic

Design a combinational circuit with 3 inputs x, y and z and 3 outputs A, B, and C. When the binary input is 0, 1, 2, or 3. The binary output is one greater than the input. When the binary input is 4, 5, 6, or 7, the binary is less than the input.

Can you help me with this assignment?

Comment: What have you done up to now to solve it?

Comment: Have you written-down the truth table?

Comment: When the binary input is 4, 5, 6, or 7, the binary is less than the input.... 1 less? 2?3?

Comment: Yes, we can.  However, we're not going to do your assignment for you.  What have you tried?  What doesn't make sense?  Did you get an answer, but you think it's incorrect for some reason?  You need to show some effort.  Please edit the question to show what you've done to solve the problem.  If you demonstrate effort, we will reopen it and help you.

Answer (score 4):

-Draw out your truth table

-create Karnaugh maps for each separate output

[Try page 163+ of this free chapter from a McGraw-Hill book](http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/dl/free/0072865164/147282/mar65164_ch03A.pdf)

-Use the Karnaugh map results to create logic circuit

-Condense circuit through common terms of Karnaugh maps results